# Unable to append a whitespace to a string in while loop

Tags: c, string, append, whitespace, strcat

this is my code down below and what it does is, takes input into variable string1 and then my while loop tokenizes each word and I'm able to reach the goal of my assignment which is to reverse the words within a string. Below my code is it's output and as you can see, there are no spaces. How can I put white space in the final string similar to the original string?

Code:

```
int main()
{
  int ch, ss=0, s=0;
  char x[3];
  char *word, string1[100], string2[100], temp[100]={0};
  x[0]='y';

  while(x[0]=='y'||x[0]=='Y')
  {
    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(string1, 100, stdin);
    if (string1[98] != '\n' && string1[99] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }

    word = strtok(string1, " \n");

    while(word != NULL)
    {
      s = strlen(word);
      ss=ss+s;

      strncpy(string2, word, s+1);
      strncat(string2, temp, ss);
      strncpy(temp, string2, ss+1);

      printf("string2: %s\n",temp);     
      word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }




    printf("Run Again?(y/n):");
    fgets(x, 2, stdin);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a String: AAA BBB CCC
string2: AAA  
string2: BBBAAA   
string2: CCCBBBAAA
```

Comment: `if (string1[98] != '\n' && string1[99] == '\0')` is undefined if the `fgets()` returned `NULL` or read less than 98 characters.

Comment: There are no white spaces because you don't append white spaces !!

Comment: Also, the sequence `strncpy(string2, word, s+1);
      strncat(string2, temp, ss);
      strncpy(temp, string2, ss+1);` practically guarantees that `temp` will end up without a null-terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply adding spaces?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int ch, ss=0, s=0;
  char x[3];
  char *word, string1[100]={0}, string2[200], temp[200]={0};
  x[0]='y';

  while(x[0]=='y'||x[0]=='Y')
  {
    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(string1, 100, stdin);
    if (string1[98] != '\n' && string1[99] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }

    word = strtok(string1, " \n");

    while(word != NULL)
    {
      s = strlen(word);
      ss=ss+s;

      /* copy the word to the working buffer */
      strncpy(string2, word, s+1);
      /* if this is not the first word, put a space after the word */
      if (temp[0] != '\0') strcat(string2, " "); /* add this */
      /* concat the previously read words after the new word and a space */
      strncat(string2, temp, ss);
      /* adjust the length of the string for the added space */
      ss++; /* add this for space */
      /* copy the new result to temp */
      strncpy(temp, string2, ss+1);

      printf("string2: %s\n",temp);
      word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }




    printf("Run Again?(y/n):");
    fgets(x, 2, stdin);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I worked. Although, could you please tell me why it worked. I don’t  understand what its doing t my program.